# Azure image has no uri - Cant create auto scale from it

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, autoscaling, azure-powershell, azure-rm-template

I have successfully created an image of a VM using packer. The instance is an Ubuntu machine installed with nginx.

Now, when i want to fire up a ressource group with a load balancer and Auto-Scaling, i need to refer this image using a URI; but when i go to the image in Azure, the URI field is empty.

[image]

How do i get this URI, so i can set up my Auto Scale enviornment, with the template below?

[image]

Best,
Jonas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i need to refer this image using a URI; but when i go to the image in
> Azure, the URI field is empty.

This is because that your Image is managed. With Managed Image, you wouldn't see the URI, just like manged disk.

> How do i get this URI, so i can set up my Auto Scale enviornment, with
> the template below?

Since your Image is managed , you cannot get the URI. However, you can still create VMSS from the managed Image with template.

You can use

```
    "imageReference": {
                  "id": "[variables('managedImageId')]"
                  }
```

You can  refer to  [this template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vmss-custom-image-existing-vnet-existing-app-gateway). This template uses the Name and Group of the image to deploy VMSS.

Hope this helps!